# How remove the previous event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tell me what I need to correct, to the repeated clicking on another cell `TR` previous events are deleted

[Full example](http://jsfiddle.net/WGdyk/1/)

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    $('table tr:even').addClass('even');

    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('visited');
    })

});
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to click on any cell "TR" (add class), then I need to remove it (after clicking on another cell "TR")

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers (click the tick on the accepted). Also, now you have a rep >=15, you can vote up. This will make folk more inclined to help you out in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by just adding a bit to your current `.click()` handler, like this:

```
$(this).click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('visited').siblings().removeClass('visited');
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WGdyk/5/).  As you get more elements though, the row level handler gets less efficient and you should look at [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead, like this:

```
$('table tr:even').addClass('even');
$('table tbody').delegate('tr', 'mouseenter', function() { 
    $(this).addClass("active");
}).delegate('tr', 'mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
}).delegate('tr', 'click', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('visited').siblings().removeClass('visited');
});​
```

[You can test that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WGdyk/6/), if you don't go this route, at least move the
`$('table tr:even').addClass('even');` outside the loop, it only needs to run once :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing what you want to do is to remove the previous selection. [Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WGdyk/4/).

Basically, in this example I'm removing the `visited` class from all sibling rows:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('visited');
```

Also, is there any reason for using:

```
$(this).closest("tr").toggleClass('visited');
```

When you can just use:

```
$(this).toggleClass('visited'); // $(this) is a <tr>
```

Comment: @Algorithm - Don't forget to mark the accepted answer like you have on your other questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can cut down your jQuery quite a lot, and cache for performance.

Here is the branched fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HTerC/

Here is the jQuery

```
$rows = $('table tbody tr');
$rows.click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('visited');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('visited');
});

$rows.hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

You'll want to wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` as well

Comment: If you're after performance this isn't any better than chaining...more importantly the biggest performance boost would be using `.delegate()`, and not doing `$(this)` multiple times inside each handler :)  Your fiddle link isn't using the code in your answer either, mis-linked? ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$('table tr:even').addClass('even');

$('table tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

That would cover the even highlighting and hover. The other suggestions will work for the visited effect.

Answer (score 1):

Made your JS more consise and I think I've sorted what you need to do

```
$('table tbody tr').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
}).click(function(){
    $(this).addClass( "visited" ).siblings( ).removeClass( "visited" );
}).filter( ":even" ).addClass('even');
```

So you have hover colouring, click for visited, deselect others, I don't know if you want to click deselect as well, if you do just change addClass back to toggleClass.